# как устроены социальные сети (внутри)

Tags: сеть

такой вопрос , давно пытаюсь найти ответ подробный , но не могу .
собственно как пишутся сети с нуля и как они вообще устроены? знаю , что трудно и затратно , но интересен сам механизм , как все пользователи связаны между собой?
где это всё хранится , в каких это всё данных обычно?
какие необходимы ресурсы для сети ? 
и распространите дальше эти вопросы , спасибо)

Comment: Технически социальная сеть это база данных, не более. Или, как принято теперь говорить, технически социальная сеть это база данных чуть более чем полностью. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Социальные сети - это нечто волшебное. 
Существуют главные маги. Чтоб было ближе к жизни, давайте возьмет тех кто ближе сейчас сердцу каждого. Цукерберг, Дуров.

Главное в разработке социальных сетей - украсть идею. Например Цукерберг ворует идею у своих коллег по учебному заведению, а Дуров в свою очередь не будь дураком - чуточку подворовывает у Цукерберга. Казалось бы самое время возмутиться автору! Но авторы на самом деле в свое время получили нормально денег и спокойно отвалили.

Как пишутся сети с нуля ? Нужно сесть за компьютер (мы же помним, что предварительно нужно украсть идею ?) и начать писать. Сначала у вас ничего. Потом начинает что появляться, а потом фигак - и соцсеть в продакшене. Рыдают и Дуров и Цукерберг. 
Ну или например у вас есть миллион долларов - можете весьма себе позволить нанять штат и написать свою соцсеть с нуля. А там уж вам объяснят специалисты как она пишется.

Есть еще один вариант. Заходите на хакерский сайт https://google.com забиваете в строке поиска "Как устроена соцсеть" и первый же ответ увидите https://xakep.ru/2011/03/16/55052/  где не будут вас стебать за вопрос, а возможно вы реально что то узнаете в этом направлении.

Уж простите если обидел. Посчитал своим долгом вам все разъяснить вместо того чтоб поставить минус. :)

Comment: не нужно делать свои соц сети , так понял основную мысль?

Comment: Уверен что большинство хороших разработчиков в свое время изобретали велосипед. Мой посыл лишь в том, что на мое усмотрение (исключительно мое мнение) , конкретно этот велосипед - не лучшая идея. Как вам верно ответили в комментарии - соцсеть это попросту база данных и большинство ресурсов тоже самое, однако стоит ли строить то что почти наверняка не будет построено? Тем не менее пробовать вам уж явно никто не будет мешать, скорее наоборот. А мой ответ больше воспринимайте как юмор, но не критику ибо художника каждый может обидеть...